# Custom django form that has fields populated from database

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.  I have a custom form that uses forms.Modelform to create a custom form from my model. I have some data in my database already that I manually input for testing.

However, the user and course field shows up as dropdowns.  But they do not have any data in the dropdown list.  How can I have django to pull data from the database and display the information into each dropdown on my form?

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
```

view.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = StudentForm()
    else:
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
return render(request, "request.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

### Update

Actually found out that the changes weren't saved to my DB.  They are now loading into the form.  However in the dropdown list, it is showing up as "Student Object", and "Course Object"

How can I make it so they show up with proper names?

Comment: Have you got any `User` and `Course` objects in the database?

Comment: Actually I realized the changes were not saved.  My dropdown can now see the objects from the DB.  however, they show up as "Student Object" and "Course Object" rather than the names.

Comment: define the `__unicode__` method for those objects.

Answer (score -1):

I would advocate that you move away from doing this if this is testing, and instead follow the guidelines for testing as outlined in the django tutorials, i.e. it creates a fake database for you and you create `Users` and `Courses` via `Users.objects.create(username=...)`